# adding gradient colour to button background in android

Tags: android

**I have a gradient background with code**:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:background="@drawable/sel_btn_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

**sel_btn_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/bluegreen"
            android:endColor="@color/aqua_marine"
            android:angle="-270" />
</shape>
```

**I get result**:

[image]

**How to achieve the below result(left side is the light colour fading to dark on right colour)** What value should be added for angle:

[image]

Comment: try change difference angle. try 90

Comment: change angle to android:angle="180"

Comment: @kishanverma ... can you post this answer .... 180 works perfectly

Comment: Devrath sure up vote for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use 180 angle instead of -270 angle

```
android:angle="360"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be 360,Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#36d1d1"
        android:centerColor="#811010"
        android:endColor="#233308"
        android:angle="360" />
</shape>
```

Replace your color values accordingly.I have used completely different color distinguishing between all 3 colors.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#278b79"
        android:centerColor="#32b39b"
        android:endColor="#38c7ad"
        android:angle="180" />
</shape>
```